# Is it possible to get a reference to the vanity URL used after redirection?

Tags: aem, urlrequest, vanity-url

I have a page `http://localhost:4502/content/project/en/mypage.html` and it has couple of vanity URLs set as

```
/content/project/vanity-1
/content/project/vanity-2
```

So any request from the above two vanity URLs are being redirected to **/mypage.html**.

Is it possible to get the vanity URL request from where the page is redirected to? i.e how can I find from which vanity URL the request is coming from?

`request.getRequestURL()` gives me .**./mypage.html** but I need to get the vanity URL request.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get it from `/content/project/page/jcr:content` properties `sling:vanityPath`

Answer (score 0):

It's available in the HTTP referer header. You can get it as follows:

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
```