# working of vanity URL CQ5

Tags: aem, vanity-url

Can someone tell me the core .js involved in the working of Vanity URL in CQ5? i.e how does the vanity URL (sling:vanityPath) redirect to a page ?

I need to imput in the CQ dialog a parameter along with the vanity URL so when a redirected page is loaded, the vanity parameter appends to the page!

Comment: possible duplicate of [vanity url & redirection CQ5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680812/vanity-url-redirection-cq5)

Comment: Hi, You may have to create a node under /etc/http with attribute sling:match and sling:internalRedirect. & For logic you can use custom Tags

Answer (score 0):

URL mapping nodes are under /etc/map 
you can also see all the active mapping including the vanity urls on http://localhost:4502/system/console/jcrresolver